# How to chop string into two variables 2 digits from the end in PHP

Tags: php, string

I want to create two variables from one string in PHP.

e.g.

```
$string = "2,50";
```

to

```
$a = "2";
$b = "50";
```

How to do that?

I want to use it to `<sup>` the cents in the price and style it differently, but I have this number as a whole. So I need to devide it into two pireces.

the format of the string is always with two decimal points and a comma as a delimiter, os this should be a little help.

Any idea how to do this using PHP?

**IMPORTANT!** I need to do that without using arrays in PHP!

Comment: Uh, what's wrong with arrays?

Comment: @jszobody Ask my teacher.

Comment: Oh. So it's homework. Bah. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`list`](http://php.net/list) construct along with [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to achieve this:

```
list($a, $b) = explode(',', trim($string));
```

[Demo.](https://eval.in/67921)

Comment: WOw, thats nice. I will try it ;D

Comment: It's working great. I will tick your answer in .. it says 7 minutses ;)

Comment: @user2989475: This solution still uses an array given by explode. `list` just makes the assignment a little bit easier. If you *really* want to do this without arrays, then you may want to use a combination of `strpos()` and `substr()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) this will give you an array with two entries, add the values of those entries to your original variables.